# How to type the matching character to «

Tags: keyboard

So option + '\' key types « but I can't figure out how to type the closing ». Can anyone point me in the right direction? Also what is the name of this symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>\</kbd>  gives «

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>\</kbd>  gives »

Character viewer calls then "Left- & "Right-pointing double angle quotation mark".